# MySQL query takes too long

Tags: mysql

I have made this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
from sat_msgPos 
where  TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,tmUpdate,NOW())<=30 
  and idTrigger = 9 
  and idVeh = 12590;
```

and an index `(idVeh,tmUpdate)` on a big table. It's much better after I created the index, but I want to make it faster.

Does anybody have a suggestion?

Comment: Try rewriting `TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,tmUpdate,NOW())<=30` to `timestampadd(MINUTE, -30, now()) >= tmUpdate` and an index on `sat_msgPos (idVeh, idTrigger, tmUpdate)` or `sat_msgPos (idTrigger, idVeh, tmUpdate)`, if `idTrigger` is more selective than `idVeh`.

Comment: Same thinks. I have made all the changes, but it takes over 1 minute to complete the query. Any other ideea?

Comment: @stickybit that suggestion should be answer. Will you add it?

Comment: @IsabellaPopa did you do everything that stickybit suggested? (see my answer as well). If yes, please edit the question and add the new execution plan (output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...;`)

Answer (score 1):

The `WHERE` codition has a function that acts on a column. This means that even if an index is used, it will have to do a complete index scan. In such cases, it is good (if possible) to rewrite the condition so the column is used bare, and any function is applied to constants or run-time constants (like `NOW()`). This way an index can be used with an index seek - and a partial index scan, only rows that are needed will be scanned.

Try rewriting

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, tmUpdate, NOW()) <= 30
```

to:

```
timestampadd(MINUTE, -30, now()) >= tmUpdate
```

and add an index on either `sat_msgPos (idVeh, idTrigger, tmUpdate)` or `sat_msgPos (idTrigger, idVeh, tmUpdate)`.